# WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing Failed to fetch

Tags: updates, do-release-upgrade, stable-release-updates

i am using Ubuntu 14.04 now i want to upgrade my Ubuntu to the latest version so i run `sudo do-release-upgrade` in terminal
then i getting the below error

> Err Upgrade tool signature
>     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>   Err Upgrade tool
>     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>   Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
>   WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
>   Failed to fetch
>   Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.

please guide me how to resolve this error.Thanks in advance.

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no supported way to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 as 14.10 *"Utopic Unicorn"* reached end of live in 2015-07-31 and Ubuntu 16.04 isn't released yet.

You need to wait until April when 16.04 will be released.

Comment: thanks i will wait.can i directly upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 after April ?

Comment: Yes.  As 16.04 is the next LTS release after 14.04 the upgrade will be officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message "404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]" you have a network issue or the used mirror is not working for utopic.
Check that you can reach the server listed in /etc/apt/sources.list, try to connect to a different server, if that also fails check your internet connection and outgoing firewall settings.

Kind regards
Maddes

Comment: You may wish to read the other answer.  And 404 Not Found is unlikely to be a network issue.  It means File Not Found, not Server Not Found. That's because those files have now been deleted from the servers.

Comment: i have a reliable net connection so i am sure this is due to not a my net connection.i tried to connect us server by default it is in India server that is also not worked.